# how to set date to current date using dos batch file command

Tags: dos, batch-file

how to set date to current date using dos batch file command.

Comment: batch files are programming too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to use the current date in a batch file, the variable `%date%` has the current date:

```
echo %date%
23/02/2010
```

It uses the format of the regional setting of your computer. In my computer it's `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Since the `/` can't be part of a file name, they must be replaced with a safe character or nothing:

```
echo %date:/=-%
23-02-2010

echo %date:/=%
23022010
```

If you want to create a backup copy of a file, you can do something like:

```
copy file.txt file-%date:/=%.txt
dir /b file*.*
file-23022010.txt
file.txt
```

Or first set it to a variable and then use it:

```
set currdate=%date:/=%
copy file.txt file-%currdate%.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The [date command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) is what you are looking for. This works on my Windows XP box:

```
date 15-02-2010
```

Notice the formatting `dd-MM-yyyy`, which seems to be required here, probably because of my regional settings being set to Denmark. The documentation states that the format is `MM-dd-yy`, but on my computer, the day and month fields gets flipped if the date is written in that format.

Comment: what to do when you dont want to hardcode the current date in the command . is there any command like date curdate()

Comment: which picks up date from bios

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you here. You can do `date /t` to **get** the current date, but your original question seems to be on how to **set** the date.

Answer (score 2):

When you type "date" on the dos command it will show you the date specified in your bios, and ask you to set the current date (you can set this if the date in your bios is not the current). The system has no ability to know if it's date is correct.

If you have a server with correct date, you can use "net time" so the the client can synchronize with the server.

```
NET TIME <SERVERNAME> /SET
```

or

```
NET TIME \\SERVERNAME /SET /YES
```

Comment: This is the only answer which actually answers the (admittedly very vague) question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have the "Set time automatically" option on:

```
net stop w32time    
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /nowait
```

Or you can save the current date to a text file and then pass the current date to the date command:

```
date /t>current_date.txt
```

OR

```
echo %date%>current_date.txt
```

Then pass the current date to the date command:

```
date<current_date.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to include the time when making the file you can use this

`C:\scripts\startup.bat >> automaton_logs_%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt 2>&1`

This command runs a script and redirects both standard out and error to a file with the timestamp of the execution when configured in a shortcut on the desktop

to see the file name it would use you can do

`C:\Users\Administrator>echo automaton_logs_%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt`

`automaton_logs_16062023_111951.txt`

Comment: The question is about *setting* the time, not about *using* the time string.

Answer (score -2):

You must take in account that US date is a bit different from europe date.
Giving Date  displayes:

```
>date
The current date is: 2019-09-12
Enter the new date: (yy-mm-dd)
But US date will be something like: mm-dd-yy
```

Better have a look at:
https://www.robvanderwoude.com/batexamples.php

Comment: Can you explain further how this information solves the given (very vague) question?