# How to get the system date as the command line parameter using VS debug tab of project properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to set the system date as the command line parameter in the debug tab of the Project Property in the Console application.

What are the value set it come as same string but i need the system date every day. Its possible?

If it would be command prompt I'd use `%date%` ([how to set date to current date using dos batch file command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264987/how-to-set-date-to-current-date-using-dos-batch-file-command)), but I can't find equivalent in Visual Studio.

Comment: You mean the properties in a `DateTime` object aren't enough?

Comment: No. Command line parameter is the separate topic. It have project level property in the solution explorer window.

Comment: But why do you need it as a parameter when you can get it directly from the system? Why are you tagging this as C#? If anything, this is a command line question, either bash, powershell, good ol' windows command line, whatever, but it seems like it has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Because I am using the C# language. I think this only directly use the command line parameter as the parameter in the main method. This is my requirement.

Comment: How you obtain and pass in parameters from the console to a C# program has nothing to do with C#. The program could be written in C, java, python or any other language for that matter and the answers are the same, it depends on what shell you're using which has nothing to do with the language. With that said, why do you need the system date to be passed in to your program from the command line when you could get it directly from the system using the programming language's APIs?

Comment: @JeffMercado if you ignore what OP comment says I think it is reasonable question (or at least in a way I read it). It is obvious how to specify current date in any shell where you can run you program, but it is not clear if one can set it via Visual Studio's debugging properties as specified in the question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Then maybe it's a Visual Studio question. Point is, this is not a C# problem if you don't use the C# tools. The question is tagged heavily with C# tags, but it doesn't have anything to do with C# at all.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, C#4 is somewhat strange... edited/re-tagged. That may not be exactly what OP had in mind, but I don't think my edit changed spirit of the question. (Plus OP can get actual answer from the edit :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Its not possible through C# Code.

We can able to send different values in run time using the help of console window. If you run the code and send the parameter next to the Exe path.

Ex:
C:\Application1.exe "2015-12-01"

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't specify dynamic parameters in Project Properties->Debug->Command Line.

As an option you can specify string constant and replace it with value of `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")` like:

```
  var dateTimeString =  (args[0] == "now")? 
            DateTime.Now.ToString("o") : args[0];
```